# Visual Studio Load Test - Run a test mix at a specified time

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, mstest, load-testing

We have set up a loadtest in VisualStudio and all is working fine. We are wanting to extend our load tests and one of the tests we want to add, we want to run only once at a specified time.

Our tests run for 10hours, this is to mimic a working day, towards the end of the day a user will perform an upload of data. this is what we are wanting to mimic. So we would want to run this only once in the 9th hour (or after 90% of the time for shorter runs)

Can anyone give advice on how/if this is possible to achieve. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Add a "Scenario" to the load test, it should contain the test to be executed. Set the [Delay Start Time](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/configure-scenario-start-delays?view=vs-2017#specify-the-delay-start-time-of-a-scenario) property of that scenario as required, also set the [Maximum Test Iterations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/configure-test-iterations-in-a-load-test-scenario?view=vs-2017) property to 1 (one).

Setting 90% of the test run duration requires doing some simple sums to convert it to an "hour:minutes:seconds" duration.

The question states *"... towards the end of the day a user will perform an upload of data"* and I interpreted that as meaning one user to run one test and so I said set the number of iterations. However, the delayed scenario could have any of the load patterns (constant, step, or goal) and so could have many users doing end-of-day uploads. If that is wanted then setting the maximum iteration may not be needed.

The number of iterations is described in [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/configure-test-iterations-in-a-load-test-scenario?view=vs-2017) as:

> The Maximum Test Iterations property controls the maximum number of test iterations to run for the scenario. Just as for the Test Iterations property in the load test run settings, this is the maximum across all users on all agents, not a per user setting.
>
> For sequential test mix, one iteration is one pass through all the tests in the mix. For all other test mixes, each test execution counts as an iteration.

Comment: Thanks. We had a feeling that this would be the way to go, but just wanted to explore if there were other ways of achieving this.

Comment: I have used the Windows scheduler and `mstest.exe` to run a load test at a specific time. That unattended test applied almost zero load, its purpose was to monitor server housekeeping activity between 2am and 4am.

Comment: When that Max test iterations is set, is that 1 test per user or 1 test overall?
We want to log in a set of users and then have each user trigger 1 test each. Im not sure if this is possible using your approach?